# add_menu_page user level in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a theme options, but I want that only editors and administrator can access to it.
Here is my code :

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'opc_create_menu');
```

function opc_create_menu() {

```
// Create new top level menu
add_menu_page(
    'Slideshow',
    'Slideshow',
    'administrator',
    'opc-theme-options',
    'opc_settings'
);

// Call register settings
add_action('admin_init', 'opc_register_settings');
}
```

I tried this

```
add_menu_page(
    'Slideshow',
    'Slideshow',
    array('administrator', 'editor'),
    'opc-theme-options',
    'opc_settings'
);
```

Or in the same function

```
    add_menu_page(
    'Slideshow',
    'Slideshow',
    'administrator',
    'opc-theme-options',
    'opc_settings'
);
add_menu_page(
    'Slideshow',
    'Slideshow',
    'editor',
    'opc-theme-options',
    'opc_settings'
);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
add_menu_page(
    'Slideshow',
    'Slideshow',
    'manage_options',
    'opc-theme-options',
    'opc_settings'
);
```

With *manage_options* only roles that can edit WP options are allowed.

Comment: Thx you ! 
I just had to add this : function my_page_capability( $capability ) {
 return 'edit_others_posts';
}
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_opc-settings-group', 'my_page_capability' );